# How to set samesite=none

Tags: javascript, web

My browser page is loaded from my server but must acquire data from another - third party.

My code to make the very first call to this third party site is:

```
    var Vurl = "https://" + info.server + "/rest/system/session";
     var Body = JSON.stringify({name: 'session', value: info.session});

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhr.open('POST', Vurl, true);
     xhr.withCredentials = true;
     xhr.send(Body);

     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
     {
       if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) 
       {
         // Get the raw header string
         var headers = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
       }
     }
```

I have to place the following someplace but I don't know where.  All the searches in google just state it's required but not how to implement it.

```
 cookie('session', info.session, { sameSite: 'none', secure: true });
```

Can you show/tell me the proper way to set the "samesite" when working with XMLHttpRequest as shown above.

Thanks

More Info:

The call shown is sending information to the third party server.  The third party reply has a "session" cookie that must replace the existing session cookie.  From what I can find - chrome will not update the cookie from the third party reply unless "withCredentials" is set to true, samesite=none, and secure.  My understanding is that all of that is set, then chrome will update the cookie in the browser.

My issue to resolve is that following the call, I open a websocket to the third party and it expects a "session" cookie in the header to be the same as returned from the XMLHttpRequest.

Is my understanding correct?  How do I implement?

More Added - Chrome warning I'm trying to implement

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://hinkle1.sipworxx.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Comment: its up to that provider to set the cookie appropriately.

Comment: Does the other server block your call? might be CORS related, you need to proxy the call in the backend

Comment: I added more info above

Comment: Added Actual Chrome warning